# Why is Factorial 1000 impossible with BigInteger?

Tags: c#, .net, math, biginteger, integer-overflow

So when you googe, it says that BigInteger in C# is infinite, but factorial of 1000 is undefined. I made this simple recursive method and it returns something very big.

```
static BigInteger faculty(int n) {

        if(n == 2)
            return 2;
        return n*faculty(n-1);
    }
```

So it's probably an overflow but does that mean that BigIntegers are not infinite?

Comment: by "faculty" - do you mean "factorial"? (I appreciate it may be an E2L issue; I'm just trying to clarify)

Comment: Before looking at the code, I would've never made the connection...

Comment: It looks like a factorial. Setting aside input tests (what happens when your input is `1`, or less than `0`? I don't think BigInteger should have any problems with `1000!`. I mean, it's kind of the entire point of this class (Not factorial of 1000, naturally, but really big numbers)

Comment: What answer did you expect? 70! is already over 10^100

Comment: `int` is not infinite, and that's the argument type...

Comment: are you saying that *google* says "factorial of 1000" is undefined; that's just a bug in Google's code; I'd wager that if you ask a sensible math-focused NLP engine: it would work fine - for example [WolframAlpha gets the right answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorial+of+1000)

Comment: Turns out google can only answer up to 170!. Try 171! and it's already undefined.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I applaud your dedication to detail that you would take the time to find that out :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Not really that much time, started with 100, then went to 200, from there it was a simple matter of divide and conquer - a few punches on the keyboard and even less clicks on the mouse and viola - We have the magic number.

Comment: minor nit: "undefined" != "infinite" - although in this case, both answers are incorrect

Comment: @insane_developer the input value is decreasing from 1000 to 2... it doesn't need to be a BigInteger

Comment: *does that mean that BitIntegers are not infinite?*. Well, to store an infinite BigInteger you would need an infinite amount of memory and to do a calculation an infinite amount of time. And you don't have any of these!

Comment: Hold on that recursive doesn't hit the maximum call stack ?

Comment: Before you ask “why” always ask “is”.

Comment: @ZoharPeled what I meant is that the multiplications are being done with integer types, which results in a new integer each time (1000x999x998x997 already overflows). The BigInteger struct has a Multiply method for that purpose. So what I'm saying is if you use BigInteger, do all your operations with BigIntegers.

Comment: @insane_developer Actually, the multiplications are being done with an int on the left side and a BigInteger on the right side....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't (impossible). The following works just fine here (tested on .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Framework 4.7.2):

```cs
var x = faculty(1000);
var s = x.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s.Length); // 2568 (digits)
Console.WriteLine(s); // 402387260...000000 (lots of digits)
```

Comment: [Actually](https://rextester.com/DVA53383), `4023872600770937735437024339230039857193748642107146325437999` [and so on....](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_nines_in_pi)

Comment: Ok thank you, I actually had the same result, then it must be google's fault because when you google 1000! it returns "1000 ! =
undefined"

Comment: @PeterPeperoni yes, that's just Google not being math-focused; if you have a maths question: ask WolframAlpha, not Google

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, WolframAlpha looks like a good option :D